# How to change url name via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I am loading url through anchor tag as -

```
<a id="A3" target="_blank"  href ="www.externalurl.com"></a>
```

When it will get loaded on another page , I want to show it as different url name in address bar-

```
www.myurl.com
```

How I could achieve this through javascript?

Or is there any way for this in dotnet?

Comment: You can't do that, it's a horrible security risk to allow it.

Comment: This is a similar question and might be of help applying to the newly loaded page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/3354511#3354511